# Diophantine equation interesting problem from geometry

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Today I came up to an interesting problem that i would like to share with the ME community to the enjoy of the reader. The initial problem (which has $2$ almost equivalent statements) was about integer sides in a triangle. This problem is (not very surprisingly) equivalent to a bit challenging problem about Diophantine-equations

**Statement $1$**

Let $\triangle ABC$ be an isosceles triangle with $\overline{BC}=\overline{CA}$. Consider the height $AD$ over side $BC$, with $D$ being the base of the height. Find all triangles such that $\overline{BD}, \overline{DC}, \overline{AB}, \overline{AD} \in \mathbb{N}$ (or $\in \mathbb{Z}$ if you consider directed lenghts)

**Statement $2$**

Let $\Omega$ be a circle with center $O$. Consider a radius $OA$, and a point $B \in OA$. Denote $C$ the point that results from the intersection of $\Omega$ with a perpendicular line to $OA$ through $B$. Find all possible configurations such that $\overline{OB}, \overline{BA}, \overline{BC}, \overline{CA} \in \mathbb{N}$ (or $\in \mathbb{Z}$ if you consider directed lenghts)

**Hint**

> Letting $u=\overline{OB}, v = \overline{BA}$, the problem es equivalent to solve the following system of Diophantine equations:\begin{align}(u+v)^2 - u^2 = v(2u +v)= x^2 \\(u+v)^2 - u^2 + v^2 = 2v(u+v) =z^2\end{align} Now, $z$ is even, so $z=2y$ and we have to solve the following system\begin{align}  v(2u +v)= x^2 \\ v(u+v) = 2y^2  \end{align}

Comment: It is a very unfortunate fact that the 'spoiler environment' does not allow for newlines. I have removed them all; the underlying text is now rather difficult to parse.

Comment: Search result of equation {$v(2u +v)= x^2 , v(u+v) = 2y^2$} with $(u,v)\lt1000.$  
$(AC,AD,AB)=(25, 24, 30),(169, 120, 130),(289, 240, 272),(625, 336, 350),(841, 840, 1160).$

Comment: Question fields are for asking questions, not for answering or hinting at answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Fact:** If $(a,b,c)\in\Bbb{N}^3$ satisfies $a^2+b^2=c^2$ then, after interchanging $a$ and $b$ if necessary, there exist $k,m,n\in\Bbb{N}$ with $\gcd(m,n)=1$ and $m>n>0$ and $mn$ even such that
$$a=k(m^2-n^2),\qquad b=2kmn,\qquad c=k(m^2+n^2).$$
Such triples are known as *Pythagorean triples*, and this parametrization has been known since antiquity. A triple with $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$ is called *primitive*, and of course has $k=1$ and $a$ odd.

---

Suppose $ABC$ is a triangle with $AB,AD,BD,CD\in\Bbb{N}$, where $D$ is as described in Statement 1. Then $AC=BC=BD+CD$, so also $AC,BC\in\Bbb{N}$, and so $(AC,AD,CD)$ and $(AB,AD,BD)$ are two Pythagorean triples. Note that $\gcd(AC,AD,CD)$ divides $AD$ and also $AC-CD$, where
$$AC-CD=BC-CD=BD,$$
and hence $\gcd(AC,AD,CD)$ also divides $AB$ because $AD^2+BD^2=AB^2$. This shows that $\gcd(AC,AD,CD)$ divides $\gcd(AB,AD,BD)$, and so the configuration $ABCD$ can be scaled down so that the triple $(AC,AD,CD)$ is a *primitive* Pythagorean triple.

Next note that at most one of the legs of a Pythagorean triple is odd. So if $AD$ is odd then $BD$ and $CD$ are even, and hence $AC=BC=BD+CD$ is even. But this contradicts the fact that
$$AD^2+CD^2=AC^2.$$
Hence $AD$ is even and so there exist $m,n,r,s,t\in\Bbb{N}$ with $\gcd(m,n)=\gcd(s,t)=1$ and $m>n>0$ and $s>t>0$, and $mn$ and $st$ even, such that
\begin{eqnarray*}
CD&=&m^2-n^2,&\qquad AD&=&2mn,&\qquad AC&=&m^2+n^2,\\
BD&=&r(s^2-t^2),&\qquad AD&=&2rst,&\qquad AB&=&r(s^2+t^2).\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Then $AC$ and $CD$ are odd, so $BD=BC-CD=AC-CD$ is even. Of course $s^2-t^2$ is odd because $\gcd(s,t)=1$ and $st$ is even, and so it follows that $r$ is even, say $r=2w$. Then
$$2n^2=AC-CD=BD=2w(s^2-t^2).$$
We also see that $AD=2mn=4wst$, and hence
$$2w(nst)=n(4wst)=n(2mn)=m(2n^2)=2mw(s^2-t^2),$$
which shows that
$$2nst=m(s^2-t^2).$$
Because $m$ and $n$ are coprime this shows that $m$ divides $2st$. Similarly, because $s$ and $t$ are coprime and $s^2-t^2$ is odd, this shows that $2st$ divides $m$. That means $m=2st$ and hence $n=s^2-t^2$. Plugging this back into our original parametrization shows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
CD&=&m^2-n^2&\qquad AD&=&2mn&\qquad AC&=&m^2+n^2\\
&=&(2st)^2-(s^2-t^2)^2&\qquad&=&2(2st)(s^2-t^2)&\qquad&=&(2st)^2+(s^2-t^2)^2\\
&=&-s^4+6s^2t^2-t^4&\qquad&=&4s^3t-4st^3&\qquad&=&s^4+2s^2t^2+t^4\\
BD&=&r(s^2-t^2),&\qquad AD&=&2rst,&\qquad AB&=&r(s^2+t^2).\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Comparing the expressions for $AD$, it is clear that $r=2(s^2-t^2)$.

Conversely, it is a matter of rote algebra to verify that
$$(-s^4+6s^2t^2-t^4)^2+(4s^3t-4st^3)^2=(s^4+2s^2t^2+t^4)^2,$$
which means that for any choice of $r,s,t\in\Bbb{N}$ with $\gcd(s,t)=1$ and $s>t>0$ and $st$ even these parametrizations yield a solution. To also meet the requirement that $CD>0$ we must have $m>n$, which is equivalent to $2st>s^2-t^2$, or put differently
$$(s-t)^2<t^2.$$
Of course $s$ and $t$ are both nonnegative, so this is in turn equivalent to $s<2t$. In conclusion:

> A triangle $ABC$ with $AC=BC$ has $AB,AD,BD,CD\in\Bbb{N}$, with $D$ as defined in statement 1, if and only if after scaling there exist coprime $s,t\in\Bbb{N}$ with $2t>s>t>0$ and $st$ even, such that
> \begin{eqnarray*}
> AB&=&2(s^4-t^4),\\
> AC=BC&=&s^4+2s^2t^2+t^4,\\
> AD&=&4st(s^2-t^2),\\
> BD&=&2(s^2-t^2)^4,\\
> CD&=&-s^4+6s^2t^2-t^4.
> \end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hints: As can be seen in figure AB, AD and DB are Pythagorean triples such that:

$DB=2 k+1$, $AD=2k(k+1)$ and $AB=2k(k+1)+1$; $k\in N$

Similarly AD , DC and AC follow the same relation. That is we can always construct such triangles with required constrains. This helps you to solve the equation you found.

Comment: The most general solution is $v=k(2m^2)$ and $u = k(n^2 - m^2)$, where $(m, n, l)$ is a primitive pythagorean triple $m^2 + n^2 = l^2$

Comment: Then $r = k(m^2 + n^2)= k(l^2)$, $x = k(2mn)$ and $z = k(2ml)$